# C# viable way to retrieve fields in HTML email body

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to retrieve fields from a `.HTML` `Outlook` emailbody.

---

Sample snippet of the .HTML content

```
</table>
</tbody>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 18.0pt 30.0pt 18.0pt">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="28%" style="width:28.0%;border:none;border-bottom:solid #7F7F7F 1.0pt;padding:3.75pt 2.25pt 3.75pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:13.5pt"><b><span style="font-size:11.5pt;font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,sans-serif;color:#333333">Title<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td style="border:none;border-bottom:solid #7F7F7F 1.0pt;padding:3.75pt 2.25pt 3.75pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:13.5pt"><span style="font-size:11.5pt;font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,sans-serif;color:#333333">:<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="border:none;border-bottom:solid #7F7F7F 1.0pt;padding:3.75pt 2.25pt 3.75pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:13.5pt"><span style="font-size:11.5pt;font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,sans-serif;color:#333333">Test Title 1</span><span style="font-size:11.5pt;font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,sans-serif;color:#333333"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="28%" style="width:28.0%;border:none;border-bottom:solid #7F7F7F 1.0pt;padding:3.75pt 2.25pt 3.75pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:13.5pt"><b><span style="font-size:11.5pt;font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,sans-serif;color:#333333">Description<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td style="border:none;border-bottom:solid #7F7F7F 1.0pt;padding:3.75pt 2.25pt 3.75pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:13.5pt"><span style="font-size:11.5pt;font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,sans-serif;color:#333333">:<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="border:none;border-bottom:solid #7F7F7F 1.0pt;padding:3.75pt 2.25pt 3.75pt 2.25pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:13.5pt"><span style="font-size:11.5pt;font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D">CLD status in description</span><span style="font-size:11.5pt;font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,sans-serif;color:#333333"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

It looks like the following in email:

[image]

May I know if there is any way that I can extract the value of `Title` and `Description`?

Edit: Seems like XPath requires specific tags to search for fields, which may be unusable in my case.

Comment: This isn’t really anything to do with EWS, it’s a question about parsing HTML, specifically the word/office flavour of HTML markup. Can i suggest you revise your tags to better reflect this?

Comment: will do. my apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [HTML Agility pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/), it was good last time I used it for similar task (many years ago).  It's a lot like XmlDocument but more tolerant for some poorly formatted HTML with unclosed tags etc.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @KolA. However, I am being restricted to install new packages in my VS. I will look into this too!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the HTML parser included in [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/docs/Basics.html)?

You may install AngleSharp into your project via NuGet.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably treat it as an XMLDocument, and use XPath queries to locate the fields.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @Robin/ I see XPath requires information of the specific tags to search for. However, the tags used are `<td>` and `<tr>`, which are very generic and occurs more than once...

Comment: @gymcode - you can do a lot more complex queries than that. For example you could look for the first td after a span that contains 'title'